# ListView setAdapter() NullPointer Exception (uses Inflater)

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I want to populate a ListView from an ArrayList, here is my code:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.verein_layout, container, false);

ListView veaList = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.veaList);
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The items get filled in here... then this code:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(inflater.getContext(),
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

veaList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Unfortunately, the code throws a NullPointerException. What do I do wrong?

Thanks in advance,

forumfresser

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: are the snippets  inside onCreateView?

Comment: What is the `getView()` you're trying to get your `ListView` from? You probably haven't returned the inflated view containing the listview back to the framework and `getView()` returns null.

Comment: try to get rid of the tripple dots `.`. Code like `fooA.fooB.GetFooC().Value` is hard to debug ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

Change the below line

```
ListView veaList = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.veaList);
```

as

```
ListView veaList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.veaList);
```

because `getView()` returns the view as **null** that's why that error . So you should use `rootView` because that the main view....

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem :( I used the getView() method for other TextViews and Buttons before, and it was no Problem with them. Blackbelt's answer below sounds interesting, but I need a solution, not a person telling me what I do wrong :) Thanks in advance

Comment: @forumfresser change to all as `rootview` because that the view.

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` returns the view you inflated and returned inside `onCreateView`, so using it inside onCreateView is wrong, because it is not yet "available".

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one...

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(inflater.getContext(),
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, items);
```